# drawString prints string over a screenshot of my current window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

When I run this code in Eclipse I get a the string and line printing in a new windows, but instead of a blank window it simply is a screenshot of my current window, set to the size I declare.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KFU0.png

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class EmptyFrame2 extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    EmptyFrame2 JF=new EmptyFrame2();
    JF.setSize(1000,500);
    JF.setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Hello",50,50);
    //g.drawLine(50-2, 50+2, 50+70, 50+2);
}
```

If this is too vague let me know and I'll change it or add whatever else you need.

Comment: Is anything else in your EmptyFrame2 class?

Answer (score 3):

- Avoid overriding `paint` of top level components
- Avoid breaking the paint chain, making super you call `super.paintXxx`
- Override `paintComponent` of something like `JPanel` instead

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `super.paint(g)` to your `paint()` method.