# How can I eliminate screen flickering on repaint?

Tags: java, swing

I made a simple game of snake in java, and am having an issue where the screen flickers whenever the screen refreshes.  Is there anything I should learn about/can implement in order to reduce and/or eliminate this?

```
public class SnakeTest extends JFrame 
{
    private boolean GAMEOVER=false; //Detect if user has a gameover

    private int score=-1;//Keeps the score ie// number of apples eaten

    MoveDown s=new MoveDown();
    MoveRight q=new MoveRight();
    MoveLeft r=new MoveLeft();
    MoveUp t=new MoveUp();

    private boolean LEFT = false;
    private boolean RIGHT = false;
    private boolean UP = false;
    private boolean DOWN = false;

    Timer downtimer = new Timer(10, s);
    Timer righttimer=new Timer(10,  q);
    Timer lefttimer=new Timer(10,   r);
    Timer uptimer=new Timer(10,     t);

    Font gameoverfont= new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 70);
    Font scorefont=new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD,30);

    //defines the snake
    int snakex=325;
    int snakey=340;
    Rectangle SNAKE=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);

    //Defines the tail
    Rectangle[] tails=new Rectangle[999];
    int[] tailx=new int[999];
    int[] taily=new int[999];

    //Defines the apple
    int applex=400;
    int appley=400;
    Rectangle apple=new Rectangle(applex,appley,15,15);
    Random ran=new Random();//Used for apple placement


    public SnakeTest()
    {
        super("SNAKE!     By Cody Antcliffe");      
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics G)
    {   
        if(!GAMEOVER)
        {
            StopAtTail();
            StopAtWalls();
            EatApple();
            G.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            G.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 700);
            G.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            G.fillRect(50, 75, 700, 575);
            Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)G;
            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2.fill(SNAKE); 
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(apple);         
            g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            for(int i=0; i<=score;i++)
                g2.fill(tails[i]);              
        }

        else
        {
            G.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            G.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 700);
            G.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            G.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 200);
            G.fillRect(0, 500, 800, 200);
            G.setColor(Color.RED);
            G.setFont(gameoverfont);
            G.drawString("Game Over!", 200, 370);
            G.setFont(scorefont);
            G.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Integer.toString(score);
            G.drawString("Score: "+score/2, 290, 450);          
        }

    }//end paint()

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            JFrame newframe=new SnakeTest();
            newframe.setIconImage((new ImageIcon("snake.png")).getImage());
            newframe.setSize(800,700);
            newframe.setVisible(true);
        }

        //handles movement down
        public class MoveDown implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                //Algorithm for tail movement
                tails[0]=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);
                tailx[0]=snakex;
                taily[0]=snakey;
                for(int i=score;i>0;i--)
                {
                    tailx[i]=tailx[i-1];
                    taily[i]=taily[i-1];
                    tails[i]=tails[i-1];
                }
                //
                snakey+=5;
                SNAKE=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);

                repaint();
            }
        }//end MoveDown

        //handles movement up
        public class MoveUp implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                //Algorithm for tail movement
                    tails[0]=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);
                    tailx[0]=snakex;
                    taily[0]=snakey;
                    for(int i=score;i>0;i--)
                    {
                        tailx[i]=tailx[i-1];
                        taily[i]=taily[i-1];
                        tails[i]=tails[i-1];
                    }
                //  
                    snakey-=5;
                    SNAKE=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);      
                    repaint();
            }
        }//end MoveUp

        //handles movement right
        public class MoveRight implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                //Algorithm for tail movement
                    tails[0]=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);
                    tailx[0]=snakex;
                    taily[0]=snakey;
                    for(int i=score;i>0;i--)
                    {
                        tailx[i]=tailx[i-1];
                        taily[i]=taily[i-1];
                        tails[i]=tails[i-1];
                    }
                //  
                    snakex+=5;
                    SNAKE=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);  
                    repaint();
            }
        }//MoveRight

        //handles movement left
        public class MoveLeft implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {       
                //Algorithm for tail movement
                    tails[0]=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);
                    tailx[0]=snakex;
                    taily[0]=snakey;
                    for(int i=score;i>0;i--)
                    {
                        tailx[i]=tailx[i-1];
                        taily[i]=taily[i-1];
                        tails[i]=tails[i-1];
                    }
                //  
                    snakex-=5;
                    SNAKE=new Rectangle(snakex, snakey,15,15);          
                    repaint();
            }
        }//end MoveLeft


        //Class for handling the arrow key presses
        private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter 
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                int direction = e.getKeyCode();

                if ((direction == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!RIGHT)&&(!GAMEOVER)) 
                {
                    LEFT = true;
                    UP = false;
                    DOWN = false;
                    downtimer.stop();
                    uptimer.stop();
                    lefttimer.start();
                }
                if ((direction == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!LEFT)&&(!GAMEOVER))
                {
                    RIGHT = true;
                    UP = false;
                    DOWN = false;
                    downtimer.stop();
                    uptimer.stop();
                    righttimer.start();
                }
                if ((direction == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!DOWN)&&(!GAMEOVER)) 
                {
                    UP = true;
                    RIGHT = false;
                    LEFT = false;
                    righttimer.stop();
                    lefttimer.stop();
                    uptimer.start();
                }
                if ((direction == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!UP)&&(!GAMEOVER))
                {
                    DOWN = true;
                    RIGHT = false;
                    LEFT = false;
                    righttimer.stop();
                    lefttimer.stop();
                    downtimer.start();
                }
            }
        }//end arrow ActionHandler


    //Collision Detection Methods
        //Detects when you hit a wall
        public void StopAtWalls()
        {
            if(snakex<=45)
            {
                lefttimer.stop();
                GAMEOVER=true;
                repaint();
            }
            else if(snakex>=735)
            {
                righttimer.stop();
                GAMEOVER=true;
                repaint();
            }
            else if(snakey>=635)
            {
                GAMEOVER=true;
                repaint();
                downtimer.stop();
            }
            else if(snakey<=70)
            {
                GAMEOVER=true;
                repaint();
                uptimer.stop();
            }
        }   //End StopAtWalls()

        public void StopAtTail()
        {
            for(int i=5; i<=score; i++)
                if(snakex-5<=tailx[i]&&snakex+5>=tailx[i]&&snakey-5<=taily[i]&&snakey+5>=taily[i])
                    GAMEOVER=true;
        } //End StopAtTail()

    //End Collision Detection Methods

        //Detects when an apple is eaten
        public void EatApple()
        {
            if(snakex-10<=applex&&snakex+15>=applex&&snakey-10<=appley&&snakey+15>=appley)
            {
                applex=gen_randomx();
                appley=gen_randomy();
                apple=new Rectangle(applex, appley,15,15);          
                score+=2; //Increase by two so that the tail grows quicker
                          //Will be corrected by dividing the final score by 2      
                repaint();          
            }
        }//End EatApple)

        /* Get new apple location*/
        //generates an x value to move apple around
        public int gen_randomx()
        {
            int Low = 50;
            int High = 730;
            int x = ran.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
            return x;
        }
        //generates a y value to move apple around
        public int gen_randomy()
        {
            int Low = 80;
            int High = 630;
            int y = ran.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
            return y;
        }
}//end main class SnakeTest
```

Comment: Make sure you only update the screen using the event thread.  Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to wrap perform all your GUI updates.

Comment: Paint on a JPanel, and override `paintComponent` instead.

Comment: Always call `super.paintComponent()` inside overridden `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: You posted a question months ago about painting (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21146397/131872). In the answer given there you were told to NOT override the paint() method and were directed to the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting`? Why did you ignore that advice? Not only have you wasted your time with this problem, but you have wasted the time of others who have taken the time to read the question. Learn how to use the forum more responsibly and that includes accepting answers when you are given help.

Answer (score 2):

Override `paintComponent` method rather than `paint` to make use of Swing's double buffering paint mechanism. Extend a `JPanel` or `JComponent` to accomodate the functionality. Make sure to invoke `super.paintComponent`.

```
public class SnakeComponent extends JComponent {
   ...

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     ...
  }
}
```

Read: [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)